# AnkhSvn not updating project in visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ankhsvn

I recently installed AnkhSvn for VisualStudio in my laptop. It was fine initially, but I did not want to commit the files in bin directory and images in css directory so I added
    "Ignore and delete"
to those folders (since i dint have a dedicated "ignore") command in the menu. After that, I tried to remove that property an I dont remember what else I did.

Now the real trouble is, when I right click on my project name and say "update to latest version" it always says skip and then ends the process. like: 
[alt text http://eternalvinay.iocleicester.com/v%20hu%20dlds/werrewwer.png](http://eternalvinay.iocleicester.com/v%20hu%20dlds/werrewwer.png)

I have right clicked on pretty much every folder and project in that solution, and even on the solution to find the filter and remove it, but in vain.

Anybody knows where I can remove that property? Now everytime I want to update my project, its a pain since i have to manually update every file and I always keep missing few and its a nasty surprise later on.

Thanks.

Comment: Which AnkhSVN version do you have and can you check if the project folder is somehow conflicted? (E.g. by looking at the status in TortoiseSVN)

Comment: @Bert, Hi, sorry, how do I check the version of AnkhSVN? it recently updated itself to the latest version though.. and yes, the folders are not conflicted (or atleast there is no mention of it anywhere)

Comment: The version information of AnkhSVN is available in the Visual Studio about dialog (Help->About)

Comment: Hi Bert, i am using : AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio 2.1.8280.494 
 * Ankh.Package 2.1.8280.494
 * Subversion 1.6.11 via SharpSvn 1.6011.1539.9366.. i guess i will contact the developers and seek assistance there, thanks a lot everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the properties with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)? AnkhSvn usually hides some files and folders.

Comment: Yes, I have tried nearly all the folders and subfolder properties through TortoiseSVN from the FileExplorer.. No luck yet.

Comment: Does updating with TortoiseSVN give the same result? If not the issue might be in AnkhSVNs SCC settings (like those found in File->Subversion->Change source control

Comment: Interesting, I never tried this, TortoiseSvn works fine!! its only through AnkhSVN.. I tried to tamper the settings of AnkhSvn, but i couldnt even find it anywhere.. will try other places in visual studio now. thanks!

Comment: Any responses to this anyone please?

Comment: Sorry.. been on vacation :) Have you tried to commit the project after deleting the property?

Comment: oh its okay! i hope you had a fun and fantastic vacation! well, the problem still persists but i have gotten used to remember to update it manually every single time!! the thing is, i am not able to delete that property!

Comment: You might try to contact the developers of AnkhSVN or ask the question on on of their mailinglists..